# jquery: find all other values except the one that triggered the function

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

**div with left class is cloned** by clicking add button by user. so it be multiple.

I need to find all other course's current values except the one which triggered this function [ already found the value in "changed_course" variable ]

```
<div id="ds_relation_main_block">




<div class="left">
    <select name="course[]" class="input-block-level course">
        <option value="55" selected="selected">BBA</option>
        <option value="56">BSc</option>
        <option value="57">BIT</option>
    </select> <!-- end of select -->
</div> <!-- end of left -->

<div class="left">
    <select name="course[]" class="input-block-level course">
        <option value="55" selected="selected">BBA</option>
        <option value="56">BSc</option>
        <option value="57">BIT</option>
    </select> <!-- end of select -->
</div> <!-- end of left -->

<div class="left">
    <select name="course[]" class="input-block-level course">
        <option value="55" selected="selected">BBA</option>
        <option value="56">BSc</option>
        <option value="57">BIT</option>
    </select> <!-- end of select -->
</div> <!-- end of left -->
```

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.course').change(function(evt) {
        var changed_course = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        //console.log(changed_course);

        //need to find all other course's current values 
        //except the one which triggered this function [ already found the value in //"changed_course" variable ]
    });

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var otherValues = $('.course').not(this).map(function() {
    return this.value
}).get();
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3FhcV/)

Answer (score 1):

The code below simply iterates over the other courses and compares them against the current course. If it isn't the current on that triggered the error, it adds it to the array.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.course').change(function(evt) {
        var changed_course = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        var self = this;

        var otherCourses = [];

        $('.course').each(function()
        {
            if (this != self)
            {
                otherCourses.push($(this).val());

                //Execute the code you want here, it will get all others individually except itself
            }
        });


        //'otherCourses' has a list of the other courses
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [:not() selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) to select all elements that do not match the given selector.

```
var not_changed_courses = $(this).find('option:not(:selected)');
```